# A quick way to justify whether $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers, congruence

Say I would like to justify whether $10^{28} \equiv 1 \pmod{29}$. I know according to Fermat's little theorem that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ when $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.  What about situations such as $7^{48} \bmod{35}$?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem applies to any $a$ that $p$ does not divide—$a$ doesn't have to be a primitive root modulo $p$.  (Standard proof: there are $p - 1$ positive integers below $p$ coprime with $p$; by Lagrange's theorem the order $n$ of $a$ modulo $p$ divides $p - 1$, so $a^{p - 1} \equiv a^{kn} \equiv (a^n)^k \equiv 1^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$.)  The rub here is that $35 = 5\cdot 7$ is not prime, so Fermat's little theorem doesn't apply—but Euler's theorem (or Carmichael's theorem) does.

Comment: Alternative (possibly simpler) proof of FLT: if you consider the binomial expansion of $(a+1)^p$ for prime $p$, you can see that all intermediate terms have constants which are a multiple of $p$, and hence modulo $p$, it becomes $(a+1)^p \equiv a + 1 \pmod{p}$.  Simple induction gives you $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ for all $a$. If $a$ is not a multiple of $p$, then multiplying by $a^{-1}$ gives $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: By Euler's Theorem $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Becasue $\phi(35)=24$, $7^{48}=({7^{24}})^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Answer (score 0):

By the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), if $n$ factors as $\prod{p_i}^{k_i}$, then
$$a^m\equiv1\pmod n\iff\forall i,a^m\equiv1\pmod{{p_i}^{k_i}}$$

Further, in $a^m\equiv1\pmod{{p_i}^{k_i}}$ we can first reduce $a$ modulo ${p_i}^{k_i}$; and by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) we can reduce $m$ modulo $\varphi({p_i}^{k_i})=(p_i-1)p_i^{(k_i-1)}$ (with the caveat that when both $a$ and $m$ are zero after said reductions, $a^m\equiv1\pmod{{p_i}^{k_i}}\iff m=0\text{ and }a\ne0$).

For $a=7$, $m=48$, $n=35$, it is enough to remark that $n=5\cdot7$, reduce $a$ to the later prime factor and notice that's zero, that $m>0$, and conclude $a^m\not\equiv1\pmod n$.

For $a=9$, $m=15$, $n=77$, it is enough to remark that $n=7\cdot11$, and check that $(9\bmod7)^{(15\bmod6)}\equiv2^3\equiv1\pmod7$ and $(9\bmod11)^{(15\bmod10)}\equiv9^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$.

---

If the factorization of $n$ is unknown, we can still compute $a^m\bmod n$ and check if that's $1$. For numbers of cryptographic interest it remains quite feasible with a computer, since [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) requires less than $2\log_2(m)$ multiplications and reductions.

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem (Lagrange)**  Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a (multiplicatively written) group. Then, for any $a \in \mathbb{G}$, $$a^{\#\mathbb{G}} =
> 1$$ where $\#\mathbb{G}$ denotes the cardinality of $\mathbb{G}$ (also known as the order of $\mathbb{G}$).

*Note:* $a^{\#\mathbb{G}}$ means $a\cdot a \cdot a \cdots a$ ($\#\mathbb{G}$ times) where $\cdot$ is the group operation in $\mathbb{G}$.

**Corollaries**

1. If $\mathbb{G} = \mathbb{F}_p^*$ then $\#\mathbb{G} = p-1$ and we get Fermat's Little Theorem: $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for any $a \in \mathbb{F}_p^*$.
2. If $\mathbb{G} = \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ then $\#\mathbb{G} = \phi(n)$ and we get Euler's Theorem: $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.